# SQLite3 not found on CMake

Tags: sqlite, cmake

I want to modify Kodi but I cannot build it because of this error.

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
Could NOT find Sqlite3 (missing: SQLITE3_LIBRARY SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
cmake/modules/FindSqlite3.cmake:28 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
cmake/scripts/common/Macros.cmake:346 (find_package)
cmake/scripts/common/Macros.cmake:360 (find_package_with_ver)
CMakeLists.txt:175 (core_require_dep)
```

Do you have a solution ? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have sqlite3 including the header files installed?  On Debian that would be the packages libsqlite3-0 and libsqlite3-dev.

Comment: When I try to install last pasckage, I've got this error : libsqlite3-dev : Dépend: libsqlite3.0 {= 3.33.0.1} but 3.34.0-1 should be install
E: Impossible to fix problems, some packages are defective and are in <<keep state>>. (Translate from French.)

Comment: Well, that would be your problem... you need to install those.  Why do you have two different versions?  It probably doesn't matter which version but it's odd you have libsqlite3.0 in one version and the -dev in another.

Comment: Version are installed like it's said in Kodi developer docs. And I cannot upgrade or downgrade libsqlite3 or sqlite3.

Comment: What os is this?  Some times you fix version issue that like by installed both packages at the same time.

Comment: It's Parrot OS (Home Edition).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and use:

sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev